# How to access router in switch mode?

Tags: dd-wrt, switch

I have an E3000 router flashed with DD-WRT. Long ago I set it up as a switch.

It was attached to a router which is now gone and I want to reconfigure the E3000.

How can I access admin panel if I don't know IP address?

Answer (score 0):

If u have set an administration port
Try to connect to it with a RJ45 and launch a scan of IP on it.
Some of software do that. You can user "Advenced Ip Scanner" for example.

Another way is the serial or COM port connector. 
COM port don't have IP address but u will be ask for an ID / Password.

Best regards.